# PuLP ignores constraints?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have listed a constraint in my code (marked below) that PuLP is ignoring. Have I defined things incorrectly? Are certain functions not allowed when adding constraints? What's the difference between lpSum and sum?

This is supposed to limit the number of non-zero items in VBPower.
(s, f) are start and finish of months in hours.

```
for (s, f) in monthHours:
    model += pulp.lpSum([bool(VBpower[i]) for i in range(s, f)]) <= 800
```

Comment: Pulp cannot handle functions like bool. You need to use binary decision variables to do counting.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Good to know! but  `for (s, f) in monthHours:
  model += pulp.lpSum([1 if VBpower[i] != 0 else 0 for i in range(s, f)]) <= 800` doesn't seem to work either. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Pulp only supports **linear models**. You are violating that in your attempts. You may want to talk to your teacher about this.

Comment: Could you please upload a minimum working example demonstrating the issue?